# Statistical testing for each row to create a volcano plot in R?

Tags: r, t-test, limma

I currently have a dataset in R where for each gene, I have the log2 expression for four daphnia exposed to copper (columns 2:5), and four control daphnia (columns 6:9). The head of the data frame is shown below:

```
           GENE_ID s_MC13_A9_Cu s_MC13_A10_Cu s_MC13_A11_Cu s_MC13_A12_Cu 

1 GENE:JGI_V11_100009     3.202503      3.152049      3.171360      3.164072    
2 GENE:JGI_V11_100036     3.241468      3.226221      3.217426      3.208969    
3 GENE:JGI_V11_100044     3.220307      3.223803      3.171068      3.228047    
4 GENE:JGI_V11_100045     3.030001      3.017256      3.028523      3.013106    
5 GENE:JGI_V11_100062     3.487595      3.471572      3.517525      3.503789    
6 GENE:JGI_V11_100066     3.576387      3.671755      3.589585      3.573903    

  s_MC13_C1_C s_MC13_C2_C s_MC13_C3_C s_MC13_C4_C
1  3.154395    3.174957   3.153786    3.188665
2  3.201010    3.211897   3.201822    3.220532
3  3.201586    3.183351   3.178189    3.178734
4  3.021061    3.023119   3.068359    3.053681
5  3.525903    3.532097   3.532113    3.530310
6  3.624656    3.534701   3.697618    3.513394
```

I want to be able to create a volcano plot illustrating differential expression and so will first need to produce P values for each of my genes. I thought about doing a t-test or Ebayes to do so, is this the best option for micro-array data? If so, how to I go about doing this, thereby generating a P value for every gene in the first column?

Thanks